# How to properly override the ReadJson method for a object[]?

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to create a json converter for an object[] to define the types I want (int32 instead of int64 for example).

This is what i got until now:

The object:

```
[JsonObject]
public class tipo
{
    public string teste { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(TestConverter))]
    public object[] metodos { get; set; }
}
```

the main:

```
    string call = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new tipo { teste="nota",
    metodos = new object[] { 10, (decimal)10.5, "Teste123" } });

    tipo t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<tipo>(call);
```

The JsonConverter:

```
namespace Newtonsoft.Json
{
public class TestConverter : JsonConverter
{
    #region Overrides of JsonConverter
    
    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
    
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        List<object> resultado = new List<object>();

        string propertyName = reader.Value as string;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            object value = null;

            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.Integer:
                    value = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                    resultado.Add(value);
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Float:
                    value = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.Value);
                    resultado.Add(value);
                    break;
                case JsonToken.String:
                    value = Convert.ToString(reader.Value);
                    resultado.Add(value);
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Boolean:
                    value = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.Value);
                    resultado.Add(value);
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Null:
                    value = null;
                    resultado.Add(value);
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Date:
                    value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.Value);
                    resultado.Add(value);
                    break;
                case JsonToken.Bytes:
                    value = Convert.ToByte(reader.Value);
                    resultado.Add(value);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.TokenType.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }

        return resultado.ToArray();
    }
    
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(object[]);
    }

    #endregion
    }
}
```

I checked the output and everything is ok, however it returns me the following error in deserialization:

> An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Unexpected end when deserializing object. Path '', line 1, position 47.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved doing this, now I have a universal converter to the formats that I want:

```
public class TestConverter : JsonConverter
{
    #region Overrides of JsonConverter

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        object value = new object();     

        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Null)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);

                List<object> resultado = new List<object>();

                foreach (var Value in token)
                {
                    switch (Value.Type)
                    {
                        case JTokenType.Integer:
                            value = Convert.ToInt32(Value);
                            resultado.Add(value);
                            break;
                        case JTokenType.Float:
                            value = Convert.ToDecimal(Value);
                            resultado.Add(value);
                            break;
                        case JTokenType.String:
                            value = Convert.ToString(Value);
                            resultado.Add(value);
                            break;
                        case JTokenType.Boolean:
                            value = Convert.ToBoolean(Value);
                            resultado.Add(value);
                            break;
                        case JTokenType.Null:
                            value = null;
                            resultado.Add(value);
                            break;
                        case JTokenType.Date:
                            value = Convert.ToDateTime(Value);
                            resultado.Add(value);
                            break;
                        case JTokenType.Bytes:
                            value = Convert.ToByte(Value);
                            resultado.Add(value);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.TokenType.ToString());
                            break;
                    }
                }
                value = resultado.ToArray();
            }
            else
            {
                JValue jValue = new JValue(reader.Value);
                switch (reader.TokenType)
                {
                    case JsonToken.Integer:
                        value = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.Float:
                        value = Convert.ToDecimal(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.String:
                        value = Convert.ToString(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.Boolean:
                        value = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.Null:
                        value = null;
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.Date:
                        value = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case JsonToken.Bytes:
                        value = Convert.ToByte(reader.Value);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.TokenType.ToString());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(object);
    }

    #endregion
}
```